# How to deal with large data in Apriori algorithm?

Tags: python, apriori

I would like to analyze customer data from my e-shop using association rules. These are steps that I took:

First: My dataframe raw_data has three columns ["id_customer","id_product","product_quantity"] and it contains 700,000 rows.

Second: I reorder my dataframe and I get a dataframe with 680,000 rows and 366 columns:

```py
customer = (
    raw_data.groupby(["id_customer", "product_id"])["product_quantity"]
    .sum()
    .unstack()
    .reset_index()
    .fillna(0)
    .set_index("id_customer")
)
customer[customer != 0] = 1
```

Finally:  I would like to create a frequency of items:

```py
from mlxtend.frequent_patterns import apriori
frequent_itemsets = apriori(customer, min_support=0.00001, use_colnames=True)
```

but now I got an error `MemoryError: Unable to allocate 686. GiB for an array with shape (66795, 2, 689587) and data type float64`

How to fix it? Or how to compute `frequent_itemsets` without using `apriori` function?

Answer (score 1):

If you have data that is too large to fit in memory, you may pass a function returning a `generator` instead of a list.

```
from efficient_apriori import apriori as ap

def data_generator(df):
  """
  Data generator, needs to return a generator to be called several times.
  Use this approach if data is too large to fit in memory.
  """
  def data_gen():
        yield [tuple(row) for row in df.values.tolist()]

  return data_gen


transactions = data_generator(df)
itemsets, rules = ap(transactions, min_support=0.9, min_confidence=0.6)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. Can you please correct your code? There are several mistakes that make it unreplicable. For example: 1. apriori returns only one variable. 2. There is no "min_confidence" argument in apriori. 3. function apriori returns `AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'size'`

Comment: I edited my answer because i used `efficient-apriori`. Sinthax was good. https://pypi.org/project/efficient-apriori/

Comment: Thanks for your effort, but your solution with `efficient-apriori` is not suitable in my case. It needs different input, does different output etc. If possible I prefer `mlxtend.frequent_patterns` solution as I write in my question.